# 22.04 fresh install won't recognise existing home folder - login loop

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, login, home-directory

can anyone help with this please?

I upgraded xubuntu 18.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. Laptop is elderly but trusty Lenovo T400. I have an encrypted home folder which I kept on a separate partition (mount point /home).  Install seemed to go fine.  However when I went to log in I got caught in the dreaded login loop.  I can log in to TT3 through ctrl + alt + F3.  I recall a simialr issue on another laptopn running ubuntu after a recent update where I fixed it by reinstalling ubuntu-desktop.

I can create new users - everything works for them.  To fix my main account I have tried every tip I could find, uninstall and reinstall xubuntu-desktop, deleting .Xauthority folder.  When I tried startx it seemed to time out.  If I can work out how I will upload the output but still figuring that out.

Can anyone suggest other solutions or guide me through a fix please?  I can usually muddle through but not a tech so full steps and clear explanations will be needed please

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was made aware of the reason on the Ubuntu forum - ecryptfs is no longer fully supported.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2491228&p=14159665#post14159665